# Small http server using java?

Tags: java, http, sockets, network-programming

I have created the following test server using java:

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class tcpServer{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket s = null;
        try{
            s = new ServerSocket(7896);
            //right now the stream is open.
            while(true){
                Socket clientSocket = s.accept();
                Connection c = new Connection(clientSocket);
                //now the connection is established
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Unable to read: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
class Connection extends Thread{
    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedReader din;
    OutputStreamWriter outWriter;

    public Connection(Socket clientSocket){
        try{
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "ASCII"));
            outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.start();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Connection: " + e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
        String line = null;
        while((line = din.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println("Read" + line);
            if(line.length()==0)    
                break;
        }
        //here write the content type etc details:
        System.out.println("Someone connected: " + clientSocket);
        outWriter.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        outWriter.write("Date: Tue, 11 Jan 2011 13:09:20 GMT\r\n");
        outWriter.write("Expires: -1\r\n");
        outWriter.write("Cache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\n");
        outWriter.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n");
        outWriter.write("Server: vinit\r\n");
        outWriter.write("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n");
        outWriter.write("<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello world from my server</body></html>\r\n");
        }catch(EOFException e){
            System.out.println("EOF: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO at run: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try{
                            outWriter.close();  
                clientSocket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to close the socket");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want this server to respond to my browser. that's why i gave url: `http://localhost:7896`
and as a result i receive at the server side:

```
ReadGET / HTTP/1.1
ReadHost: localhost:7896
ReadConnection: keep-alive
ReadCache-Control: max-age=0
ReadAccept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
ReadUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10
ReadAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
ReadAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
ReadAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
ReadCookie: test_cookie=test cookie
Read
Someone connected: Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=36651,localport=7896]
```

And a blank white screen at my browser and source code also blank. In google chrome browser.

So can anyone please tell me where i m wrong. actually i am new to this thing. so please correct me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok this worked after adding one more \n after the headers. So thanks all for their support

Comment: Hey but still one thing that seems me odd that addr of browser being 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1?? what this means

Comment: A pointer to you if you dont know already - "How Tomcat Works" by Budi Kurniawan , Paul Deck  is a good start point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to be using `DataOutputStream` on the response - and `writeUTF` certainly isn't going to do what you want. `DataOutputStream` is designed for binary protocols, basically - and `writeUTF` writes a length-prefixed UTF-8 string, whereas HTTP just wants CRLF-terminated lines of ASCII text.

You want to write headers out a *line at a time* - so create an `OutputStreamWriter` around the socket output stream, and write to that:

```
writer.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
writer.write("Date: Tue, 11 Jan 2011 13:09:20 GMT\r\n");
```

etc.

You may want to write your own `writeLine` method to write out a line including the CRLF at the end (don't use the system default line terminator), to make the code cleaner.

Add a blank line between the headers and the body as well, and then you should be in reasonable shape.

EDIT: Two more changes:

Firstly, you should read the request from the client. For example, change `din` to a `BufferedReader`, and initialize it like this:

```
din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),
                                               "ASCII"));
```

then before you start to write the output, read the request like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = din.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Read " + line);
    if (line.length() == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, this wouldn't be appropriate for a full HTTP server, as it wouldn't handle binary PUT/POST data well (it may read the data into its buffer, meaning you couldn't then read it as binary data from the stream). It's fine for the test app though.

Finally, you should also either close the output writer or at least flush it - otherwise it may be buffering the data.

After making those changes, your code worked for me.

Comment: Hey jon i have done that as you told me but still getting the same error

Comment: @codeomnitrix: You need to close the writer before you close the socket - either that, or at least *flush* the writer. Will edit to mention that.

Comment: @codeomnitrix: You also need to read the request, at least from Chrome - I've edited the answer in include that. But note that the code in your question still doesn't have a blank line between the headers and the body. You need an *empty line*, e.g. `outWriter.write("\r\n")`.

Comment: hey jon i have done that much and pretty good response as error gone away but still blank browser screen without any source code. And secondly would you please tell me what does that means by having close the writer earlier than socket.

Comment: The `BufferedReader` is not appropriate for reading incoming HTTP requests as soon as there is a message entity which might contain binary data (i.e. file upload of an image using PUT/POST).

Comment: Hey Partlycloudy ya true. but first i have to create this simpler one but its not working as i m getting blank html page at browser. so can you please tell me about that. and thanks for your response

Comment: @PartlyCloudy: That's certainly true for a general HTTP server... but just to get this working, it seemed like an easy approach :) Will edit the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I see your point that this was the right help suggested in this case. Just wanted to make clear that this is generally not the best solution however.

Comment: @PartlyCloudy: Yup, it was a helpful comment. Let me know if you feel the clarification isn't strong enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in learning the design and development of network servers like HTTP servers in Java, you might also have a look at this repo:

https://github.com/berb/java-web-server

It's a small HTTP server in Java I started for educational purposes. Though, it shouldn't be used in production or serious use cases yet. I'm still adding new features. It currently provides multi-threading, static file handling, Basic Authentication, logging and a in-memory cache.

**EDIT**

An obvious error in your code is the missing \r\n between your Response Header and your HTML. Just append an additional `\r\n` to your last header. Additionally, you must provide the content length, unless you're using Chuncked Encoding:

```
String out = "<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello world from my server</body></html>\r\n";

outWriter.write("Content-Length: "+out.getBytes().length+"\r\n\r\n");
outWriter.write(out);
```

Comment: kk thanks partlycloudy that solved but what does the address or browser means which is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Comment: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` is `localhost` when using IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

- The HTTP protocol is ASCII based, exept the body which depends on the Content-Type header. So, no UTF-8 headers!
- Headers and body must be separated by an empty line.
- Why do you set your Transfert-Encoding to chuncked? Your body is not.

Comment: hey can you please give me a single line as an example how to write the headers

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it's already done for you:

http://www.mcwalter.org/technology/java/httpd/tiny/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you have can use writeUTF instead, instead you may need to use `writeBytes`. Also, you need to terminate each line with a `'\n'`.

Comment: Hey i have made changes to my code but still getting the same error on google chrome. please check this

Comment: Hey abdullah i have edited the code and now its working but i found a blank output at google chrome with page source also blank

Comment: You need to terminate each header with \r\n. You don't need to line-terminate the body at all.