# java networking related problem

Tags: networking

Sorry for i can't precisely specify the title.

I want to ask that i have created a server using ServerSocket class in java. and i am able to run it easily using 127.0.0.1:7896 and can fetch page from the browser. You can check out this using `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655355/small-http-server-using-java`

But when i try to run this with my external ip address it doesn't worked. So can anyone please tell me whether i am conceptually wrong or it is possible. if it is then how to?

Thanks

Comment: what you you mean with "external ip"? the public ip you received from your ISP?

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking incoming connections on port 7896 or are you natted?

Comment: ya external ip means what you checked using whatismyip.com.

Comment: @Francessco i am using ubuntu 10.10 i don't know whether it do have any firewall or not.

Comment: and one thing more my external ip address gives my dslrouter page opened

Comment: @Francessco it is just blank result nothing was displayed

Comment: ok..so your router nat your pc. You have to forward incoming connections on port 7896 to your local ip (192.168.something I guess) on port 7896. This could be done on your dslrouter admin page if it support this kind of configuration

Comment: hey would you please explain it a bit more how to do this

Comment: Basically you are behind a router so your pc has a private ip address which is unreachable from the outside network. You need to tell to your router to forward all incoming traffic on TCP port 7896 to your internal IP on port 7896. Usually modern router call this kind of configuration "port fowarding rules". Checkout on your router user guide

Comment: Hey thanks francessco i am trying but didn't yet find anything as you told. but i will try it later on with my modem guide.

Comment: Can you say, what ip ifconfig command shows you?

Comment: inet addr: 192.168.1.2 Bcast: 192.168.1.255 Mask: 255.255.255.0

Comment: nd one more thing it do show when i type 192.168.1.2:7896 the web page i want but not using the external ip

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a router or somekind of firewall ? Your own Operating system may be blocking the call.

there is no reason why you shouldnt be able to do it by using the external ip, as long as the DNS knows it and your machine and infrastructure allows the call

Comment: i m having a broadband connection and using ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: You connecting directly your computer to your modem? If so it might be an ubuntu safety configuration.

Comment: hey but can't i edit my local dns file to have this known. as dns uses distributed technique and i think there is one small copy on my computer as textbooks i read, says